# docker-compose with user still creating folder as root

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I have a `docker-compose.yml` as follows:

```yaml
version: "3.4"
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: ../web/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-local
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    user: ${CURRENT_UID}
    volumes:
        - ../web:/web
        - web_node_modules:/web/node_modules/
volumes:
  web_node_modules:
```

The `Dockerfile-local`:

```
FROM node:12-alpine

# having these lines
# commented or not doesn't change anything
# VOLUME ["/web"] 
# VOLUME ["/web/node_modules"]

WORKDIR /web


EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["sh", "-c", "npm install ; npm run watch-tests"]
```

I set `CURRENT_UID` as follows in `start.sh`:

```sh
export CURRENT_UID=$(id -u):$(id -g)

docker-compose up
```

We have binary dependencies, so we need to keep `node_modules` them separate between container and host (for VS Code).

Problems:

1. If `node_modules` on the host doesn't exist, the folder is created by `docker-compose`, albeit it stays empty, but ownership is set as `0:0`. This is problematic when I try to do `npm install` locally, as I don't run that as `0:0`
2. My docker container fails because it tries to do `npm install` as `CURRENT_UID`, but even inside of the docker container `node_modules` is owned by `0:0`. This fails.

Solution:
I can fix this by creating `node_modules\.gitkeep` and still ignoring `node_modules`, or by updating my scripts to always create that folder on the host before launching `docker-compose`.

Question:
Is there a better way to solve this? Can I force `docker-compose` to create the folder `node_modules` on my system, and inside of the docker container as `CURRENT_UID`?

Comment: If you delete the entire `volumes:` block, Docker will use the code and `node_modules` trees built into the image, and the user-ID mismatch with the host won't be an issue.  You can do day-to-day development and unit testing with a host Node installation, and re-run `docker build` when needed for integration testing and deployment.

Comment: @DavidMaze that doesn't work as the Dockerfile only exposes 1 volume, and I'm hacking around that.

Comment: The Dockerfile for a typical Node-based application wouldn't have any `VOLUME` directives at all; and even if it did that shouldn't have an effect on what code gets `COPY`ed into the image and what packages `RUN npm install` installs.  Maybe editing the question to include the Dockerfile and other scripts necessary to demonstrate the issue would help clarify things.